# Java spinner (JSpinner) want to set a custom date

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner, custom-datetimepicker

I had the JSpinner as the given below date format.It takes only the current time as value. But my problem is I want to make it like default value as 12:00 am|11-11-2021  (any values but custom).

```
From_spinner = new JSpinner(); 
From_spinner.setEnabled(true);
From_spinner.setFont(new Font("Bitstream Charter", Font.PLAIN, 20));                        
From_spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, 
java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
JSpinner.DateEditor te1 = new JSpinner.DateEditor(From_spinner, "hh:mm aa|dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: `JSpinner` has built-in support for fir the old `Date` class, not for java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. So you may want to look for a date picker that supports java.time, there are some.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I already planned for it ..But I thought its GUI would looks good..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_setfield1.htm
You can use custom object of calendar and use it as a JSpinner value.
Example set year and date as you need in object and use it in you spinner.